# Why are my textures showing up in Internal but not Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

This is probably a stupid question because I'm new to Blender. I have some imported objects from XNALara to Blender that at first glance come with their respective textures integrated, and they show up perfectly in Blender Render.
[image]

But when I change this to Cycles, the textures disappear.
[image]

And I would have to manually add each texture to every object. Is there a way to make the textures show in Cycles as well? The render preview also comes out with no textures.

**Edit**: I think this is the shader editor? I'm not sure
[image]
[image]

The second picture I just added is the materials that came with the model. I sort of understand that if there are no nodes then the textures wont' show up in cycles but at the same time I also tried to add nodes and when I did, I lost a material (in Internal). So it's a weird situation, because the textures are present in Internal, like they're integrated to the objects, but only as textures and not shaders? I don't know much about this.

Comment: Could you please show the Shader Editor window? You need a shader before the Output

Comment: @moonboots Yes I will add it to the question

Comment: Why are you using an out-of-date version of Blender, and what version is it?

Comment: @TheLabCat What do you mean out of date? Like the version? It's 2.79 I saw that there are newer ones but my computer doesn't work with 2.80 and onwards, I tried to download 2.80 and when I opened it it closed on startup. Is it illegal to use previous version?

Comment: Yes, by “out of date version of Blender” I do mean that the version of blender is out of date. Please don’t skim. Okay, that makes sense. No, of course it’s not illegal (please put the sarcasminator down, I have a family), I just wanted to make sure you weren’t using it based on a misunderstanding as older versions of blender are harder to support, and also deambiguify the exact version in case of patched bugs or changed features. It is 2.79b, right?

Comment: @TheLabCat , Uh, I was not being sarcastic. I thought it could be illegal like with Adobe products and your question sounded like you were after me. I dont know how to tell what version it is. Do you know if theres a way to connect the Internal textures to the Cycles ones? Otherwise it's no problem I'll just make new materials

Comment: Oh, sorry lol. No, it is not illegal, but I’m wondering if you possibly downloaded it from an untrustworthy source if you didn’t know that (or maybe you’ve just had it all this time). The Blender Foundation expressly hosts old blender downloads of the last bugfix for each version. You can tell the version from the splash screen. I don’t remember very well, but I think the shaders between the two render engines are incompatible.

Comment: Blender Render doesn't exist nowadays so some of us don't even know why it would show in that and not Cycles.

Comment: @TheLabCat oh ok, I downloaded it from the official Blender site so it might just be incompatible. I guess manually adding each texture it is

Answer (score 2):

Cycles is not able to use Blender Internal materials directly ... you would have to enable **Use Nodes** and recreate material. For simple Diffuse shader ...

[image]

... or there was some addon that converts materials for you in some limited way.